# How to pass IV for CRYPT facade at Laravel in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, cryptography

I am unable to find a method in which I can pass **IV**(Initialization Vector) to **CRYPT facade** of **Laravel framework in PHP**

It appears as if it somehow internally implements it.

If it internally implements this, any way I can get the IV used for a particular encryption ?

```
$string = 'Some text to be encrypted';
$encrypted = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encrypt($string); // found NO way to pass IV here
$decrypted_string = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you source dive the `Encrypter` you can see how the `encyrpt` method works:

```
public function encrypt($value, $serialize = true)
{
    $iv = random_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher));

    // ... rest of the method
}
```

So yes, this is internally implemented.

> any way I can get the IV used for a particular encryption ?

Looking at the `decrypt` method:

```
public function decrypt($payload, $unserialize = true)
{
    $payload = $this->getJsonPayload($payload);

    $iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);

    // ... rest of the method
}
```

So it is possible to get the IV used.

Although you'll have to get this out yourself.

Take a look at the `Encrypter` to see what's going on; `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php`